What is the meaning of 'conservative' in left-conservative?
Reportedly the BSW and Smer are in talks to form a new Europaliementarian group of "left-conservatives". What's the meaning of 'conservative' in this context? I'm guessing it's on the cultural angle ("economically left-wing and socially conservative") , but I'm not entirely sure what "socially conservative" means in this context.
'Linkskonservatismus' seems to be how BSW self-identifies. I'm asking what BSW and Smer have in common that can be deemed 'socially conservative' values/positions.  E.g. against LGBT etc.? Against immigration?

It seems among political scientists the more common term is "left-authoritarian". A 2023 paper

Wagner, Sarah, L. Constantin Wurthmann, and Jan Philipp Thomeczek. 2023. Bridging left and right? How Sahra Wagenknecht could change the German party landscape. Politische Vierteljahresschrift 64:621–636.

cites a two-dimensional model for Western societies:

In order to encompass the entire political space in Western societies, Lefkofridi et al. (2014) outline four basic ideological preferences: economic right/sociocultural liberal, economic right/sociocultural authoritarian, economic left/sociocultural liberal, and economic left/sociocultural authoritarian. As Van der Brug and Van Spanje (2009) and Thomassen (2012) show, there are significant voter groups in all four quadrants of the two-dimensional political space in Western Europe. However, while numerous parties in Western Europe represent the political views of those in the right-liberal, right-authoritarian, and left-liberal quadrants, a notable gap exists in terms of party representation in the left-authoritarian quadrant (Lefkofridi et al. 2014).

The article argues that a (at that time speculative) new Sarah Wagenknecht party would be able to fill the gap in the economic left/sociocultural authoritarian quadrant. They support the thesis with the results of a survey conducted in November 2022.

Wagenknecht’s profile is characterized by Eurosceptic and anti-immigration stances, while still maintaining strong pro-redistribution preferences. In her book Die Selbstgerechten [The Self-righteous], published in 2021, Wagenknecht argues that being left-liberal is a newly framed neoliberalism, and she positions herself contrary to her party’s progressive cultural ideals...Our main focus in this research is to assess the potential appeal of Wagenknecht compared to The Left. Specifically, we are interested in examining those voters who view Wagenknecht more favourably than The Left.

The survey contained a number of questions to shed light on the explanatory factors that lead voters to prefer Wagenknecht. The following grafic shows the probability of matching these factors among potential Wagenknecht voters:

The appendix lists the detailed questions behind the factors:



Factor
Question
Answers




West-East
And in which federal state do you live?
List of the 16 federal states.


Class
There is a lot of talk today about the different strata of the population. Which class do you consider yourself to be?
(1) lower class (2) working class (3) lower middle class (4) middle class (5) upper middle class (6) upper class


Dissatisfaction with democracy
And how satisfied or dissatisfied are you - all in all - with democracy as it exists in Germany?
(1) not at all satisfied (5) fully satisfied


Support for democracy
How important is it for you to live in a country that is governed democratically?
(1) not important at all (11) definitely important


Socio-cultural Dimension
In politics, one often speaks of "liberal" and "conservative" regarding social issues. Conservative stands, for example, for the emphasis on traditional values. Liberal stands for openness to alternative lifestyles, for example. 1 stands for liberal and 11 for conservative. What is your own position on this?
(1) liberal (11) conservative


Socio-economic dimension
In politics, it is often debated whether the state should intervene more or less in the economy. 1 means that the government should play an active role in the economy. 11 means that the government should not intervene in the market at all. What is your own position on this?
(1) the government should be actively involved in the economy (11) the government should not intervene in the market at all


Anti-Immigration
Immigrants should be obliged to adapt to German culture.
(1) strongly disagree (5) strongly agree



A newer paper

Jan Philipp Thomeczek: Bündnis Sahra Wagenknecht (BSW): Left-Wing Authoritarian — and Populist? An Empirical Analysis. Politische Vierteljahresschrift 65: 535–552

characterizes the positions of the first BSW manifesto like this:

References to left-authoritarianism are also found in BSW’s first manifesto (Bündnis Sahra Wagenknecht 2024). The party heavily criticises the government’s climate and immigration policies as a burden for crisis-ridden Germans. The BSW also speaks of a spreading “political authoritarianism” that “dictates people how to live, heat, think and speak.” So far, such positions were associated with the far-right AfD, which is why commentators and academics see a high potential for the BSW among AfD voters (Wagner et al. 2023 [the above paper]; Wagner 2023; Petersen 2024). Regarding economic and welfare issues, the BSW criticises the growing social injustice and the power of digital multinationals. The party describes the taxation system as unfair.
Besides cultural and economic issues, another important issue for potential BSW voters is foreign policy (Ehni 2023). The BSW demands peace negotiations to end the war between Ukraine and Russia and describes NATO and the United States as drivers of military conflicts. Sanctions against Russia are seen as harming Germany’s economy. Again, these are positions that have so far been associated with the AfD (Beltin et al. 2023).


It would be more useful to relate this to Smer policies as well, i.e. what 'socially conservative' positions they have in common with the BSW.

And TBH "Immigrants should be obliged to adapt to German culture." being labelled straight out anti-immigration is slightly weird. "Cultural assimilation" or assimilationism  seems a more suitable descriptor for that.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever - Conceptually, sure, at the individual level, there are many people with more or less assimilationist beliefs who support increased immigration. Not least because many immigrants themselves actually are quite assimilationist in many countries! But at a statistical level, people who vocally express assimilationist beliefs often are actually anti-immigration, and what they really mean is something like "I am fine with immigration if they are like us or can become like us, but they are not like us and don't want to be, so...."

That is what underlines Trump and Vance's recent rants about Haitians supposedly eating pets. It's an assertion that they are not like allegedly real (White) Americans and have no interest in assimilating, but the key is that it is invented: it's not assimilationist pro-immigrant forces organically reacting to an actual failure of assimilation, but anti-immigrant forces imagining one as justification for their pre-existing desire to get rid of immigrants.

The chart is hard to read because it isn't obvious which direction the plus and minus directions are aligned with.


I'm guessing it's on the cultural angle ("economically left-wing and socially conservative") , but I'm not entirely sure what "socially conservative" means in this context.

Neither am I.
I think overall we are talking about what used to be called "the working class" and the politics associated with it. People who want better wages and want to take back economic control from the rich, and are not moved strongly by any non-economic issues.
I don't agree with other answers which equate this with "authoritarianism" - in general it is about reimposing grassroots democratic control over the authoritarianism which the rich exert through market influence.

E.g. against LGBT etc.? Against immigration?

I would say it covers cynicism about the grounds on which liberals facilitate immigration - to attack wages and disrupt the growth of solidarity and organisation amongst settled communities - and it covers a weariness with liberal identarianism on sexual matters.

Authoritarianism is a bit of point, though. But there are probably differing positions regarding which one is the authoritarian side: the legislation that forces societal actors to accept LGBT+ persons as equal, or the one that defines familial relations as only covering heteronormative models? The one that includes immigration as a part of society and allocates resources to securing their livelyhood, or the one wanting to prohibit immigration?

Linkskonservatismus seems to be how BSW self-identifies. That they don't call themselves authoritarian is perhaps a bit unsurprising. Most [economically] left wing parties only attribute that to the right-wing. Even North Korea's party does that etc.

The accusations of authoritarianism against the BSW seem to come from her expressed admiration for Stalin, at least a while back. However that's somewhat tangential  to my Q.

@ccprog, I don't think being for or against particular sexualities is what moves this group. I think they wish to prohibit mass immigration largely because they understand the connection between it and attacks on their own and their children's livelihoods, as opposed to anything strongly intrinsic to the migrants themselves.

With all due respect but "grassroots"? A party that is founded, championed and even NAMED after a single person? Like BSW stands for "Bündnis Sahra Wagenknecht" and which apparently gets most of it's financing from big money donors? https://www.tagesspiegel.de/politik/geldsegen-fur-wagenknecht-partei-bsw-erhalt-vier-millionen-euro-spende-11419616.html

Also while immigration of skilled workers is actually pushed for (though not just by "liberal" parties), most "immigrants" are actually refugess, where the point isn't about economic benefits but humanitarian responsibility or you know an anti-social fuck all attitude completely contrary to solidarity. Also is it solidarity if that is coupled with some sort of racism?

@haxor789, sometimes not even the rich can stand a society governed by the rich. After all Engels, a capitalist factory owner, famously stood on a Manchester street corner lecturing another capitalist factory owner about the conditions of the town - and the glib response he got, infamous.

@haxor789, humanitarianism is not what drives liberals to smash up all the coast of North Africa, then claim to be rescuing the victims. Just like their crocodile tears with Israel now, the corrupt "democratic" regime they backed in Afghanistan for 20 years, or the overthrow they bankrolled in Iran generations ago.

@Steve Sorry but whom do you call "liberals" here? Like classical liberals U.S. leftwingers, proponents of a market economy (might have a rough awakening looking up Wagenknecht...). Like you seem to be to deeply caught up in grand narratives that just no longer or never really fit reality.
